# Find path of Makefile inside Docker - shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, makefile, rspec

I have a docker with the following directory:
~/specs/scripts. There I have file.c and correspoding Makefile. Addtionaly I added C_util.sh in same directory which is:

```
set -e
make -f Makefile
```

I want to do Ruby tests by having a file ~/specs/helpers/shared_endpoints/Cutil.rb.

There I write:

```
    describe 'the script' do
        include Rspec::Bash

        let(:stubbed_env) { create_stubbed_env }

        it 'runs the script' do
            stdout, stderr, status = stubbed_env.execute(
                '${PWD}/specs/scripts/C_util.sh',
```

However Makefile is not found in the right directory and I have exit code 2. My question is how to navigate to the Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons.

1) Your string interpolation is wrong, String interpolation works with `#{}` in Ruby but better use `File.join`

```rb
File.join(Dir.pwd, "scripts", "C_util.sh")
```

2) For more debugging I recommend to print the path to the console with

```rb
puts File.join(Dir.pwd, "scripts", "C_util.sh")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would help you. Replace

```
'${PWD}/specs/scripts/C_util.sh'
```

with

```
File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', '..', 'scripts', 'C_util.sh')
```

Explanation:

- The script is located at `~/specs/scripts/C_util.sh`
- The test is located under `~/specs/helpers/shared_endpoints/Cutil.rb`
- `File.dirname(__FILE__)` returns the path of the current file, so it will always return the path of the Cutil.rb file.
- From the ruby file to get to the sh script, we need to jump three times to the parent directory (one to get to *shared_endpoints*, one to get to *helpers* and one to get to *specs*). From there, we have to go inside the folder *scripts*, and finally specify the file `C_util.sh`. This is exactly what the new command is doing.